# Botframework - Bot working properly with Emulator but nothing with any published channel

Tags: node.js, botframework

I've been tinkering around with the `nodejs` bot framework. I was sucessfuly able to create a bot that sends proactive messages but it just so happens that it is only working with the `emulator`.

It works on my local server and also on my remote server at https://chatobot.ngrok.io/api/messages

So far so good.

However, after going through the registration process at https://dev.botframework.com and "sucessfuly" publish it at the Skype Channel and Telegram channel, nothing happens. The bot won't reply and nothing is hitting my server's endpoint.

I've used the `Test` feature you find on the botframework website. It send's my message, but it seems to never reach my server. Also, as far as I can tell, it doesn't give me any error.

[image: Botframework Test window]

[image: Skype. Bot apparently Online and properly registred]

However, when I connect to my remote server using the `Emulator` everything works...!

[image: Working with Emulator]

What I have done:

- Made sure my `MS_APP_ID` and `MS_APP_PWD` are properly set as environment variables.
- Started by serving my `api` with `HTTPS` using `nginx` (with a self-signed certificate) and later with `ngrok` (just to make sure it wasn't a problem with my own certificate).
- Tried to add more Channels (Slack and what not) to make sure it wasn't a problem specific to Skype or the Web Chat.
- Looked for similar problems on SO. There are quite a few, but usually those people are able to solve their problem by updating they APP_ID and APP_PWD (which I've also tried) or even getting some sort of feedback in the form of an error...unfortunately it's not my case :|

PS: Don't mind my MS Paint skills.

PS2: Here's my code https://github.com/assimoes/chatobot

Comment: where is your bot hosted?  If not on Azure does your remote server have a valid certificate?

Comment: @JasonSowers, thanks for asking. I have my server hosted at [Linode](https://www.linode.com), but for that reason I have opened an http tunnel with ngrok. So I'm serving my messaging endpoint using the `https` tunnel of ngrok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I could confirm the origin of the problem is obviously at my remote server. What happens is that if I run my server as a linux service, for some reason the endpoint is never hit...however, if I run `node index.js` at the console everything works?

I will try to research more on to why this happens, but any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

## UPDATE

So I finally figured this out. So what was happening was that I had the following `systemd` configuration for my nodejs api:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/bot.service
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Chatobot server
    
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /www/chatobot/index.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-chatobot
User=chb
Environment=NODE_ENV=development PORT=8009

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What this meant was that when I started the service, the environment variables with my `APP ID` and my `APP PWD` were not accessible to the running process. To solve this issue, I just had to change the `systemd` script to this:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/bot.service
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Chatobot server
    
[Service]

Environment=MS_APP_ID=<MY APP ID>
Environment=MS_APP_PWD=<MY APP PWD>

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /www/chatobot/index.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-chatobot
User=chb
Environment=NODE_ENV=development PORT=8009

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This solved everything.